# Node/Twilio multiple config variables in require function

Tags: node.js, twilio, require, sendgrid

I was wondering if any other people have managed to find a way to use multiple account sids and auth tokens when using Twilio for Node. The documentation is pretty straight forward, and I am able to use Twilio with my own credentials.

However, while using subusers on Twilio, I want to be able to use their credentials in the process of purchasing a phone number. I currently have a app.post route which first fetches the sid and auth token of the specific user.

```
let twilioSid = process.env.REACT_APP_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
let twilioAuthToken = process.env.REACT_APP_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

let twilioClient = require('twilio')(twilioSid, twilioAuthToken);
```

Before doing the actual "purchase" of that number, I retrieve the subuser sid and auth token and update my variable before I call the function, like so:

```
const user = await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).get()
                
twilioSid = user.data().sid;
twilioAuthToken = user.data().authToken;

const purchase = await twilioClient.incomingPhoneNumbers.create({phoneNumber: number})
```

The purchase works, but only for my main (parent) account with the credentials stored in `.env`. It seems that the top variables never actually gets updated before the incomiingPhoneNumbers.create gets called. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I would be able to use the subuser credentials to run this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the variables only won't do the job here because you already initialized the client. It should work when you reinitialize the client (or just init another client):

```
const user = await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).get()
                
twilioSid = user.data().sid;
twilioAuthToken = user.data().authToken;

twilioClient = require('twilio')(twilioSid, twilioAuthToken);

const purchase = await twilioClient.incomingPhoneNumbers.create({phoneNumber: number})
```

or

```
const user = await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).get()
                
twilioSid = user.data().sid;
twilioAuthToken = user.data().authToken;

const userClient = require('twilio')(twilioSid, twilioAuthToken);

const purchase = await userClient.incomingPhoneNumbers.create({phoneNumber: number})
```

Comment: Great tip, thanks! Appreciate it.